# Not able to display KML file - OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I tried to load my KML file from one of the OpenLayers [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html?q=kml)

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import KML from 'ol/format/KML.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new BingMaps({
    imagerySet: 'Aerial',
    key: 'my-own key'
  })
});


var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: '250K_GSI_DRM_Angul_Geology.kml',
    format: new KML({
        extractStyles: true
    })
  })
});


var map = new Map({
    layers: [vector, raster],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new View({
        center: [85.1510, 20.84440],
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      zoom: 6
    })
  });
```

I can able to load the Bing maps but I can't see the KML file (file is in the same folder-path is right), even while debugging in Chrome I can't see the file in Sources tab(chrome developer tools).

[image: bing maps - output]

I don't understand where I am doing the mistake, I'm struggling two days to find out this error, am I missing any basics of OpenLayers?

Comment: What does the KML contain?  OpenLayers will only load vector features, some KMLs only contain raster data as ground overlays.  Do you see the file in the Network tab? (you will need to keep the tab open and reload the map)

Comment: Hi Sir., Thanks for the timely reply and [link] https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wQ7pvHviKuS0u_qi7FKEV_Bp45o8dlw2?usp=sharing      I shared my file please have a look. **250K_GSI_DRM_Angul_Geology** file which I tried to load.

Comment: Hi, @Mike as you asked you asked I didn't see any file in the Network tab. (I tried as you suggested)

Comment: Your file looks good, it works with the OpenLayers drag and drop example.  I think it may be hidden on your map under the Bing layer.   Try changing `layers: [vector, raster],`  to `layers: [raster, vector],`

Comment: Yes, I did, I Changed as `layers: [raster, vector],` but no luck. the results are the same as like the old screenshot. I don't know where I am doing mistake

Comment: is there any other options, how do I load my kml file, expecting the possible solutions. Thanks @Mike

Comment: when I build my code using npm and load from local drive I'm getting an error **Access to XMLHttpRequest at**   full error `featureloader.js:102 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Development/ol-ved/dist/try.kml' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ featureloader.js:102` for your reference I uploaded the screenshots [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wQ7pvHviKuS0u_qi7FKEV_Bp45o8dlw2?usp=sharing] @Mike

Comment: Chrome doesn't let pages load data by xhr from a local drive on a PC.  It will work with Edge, but on Chrome the data must also be on localhost. It's working for me.  It even works when I link directly to the download link on your google drive `url: 'https://doc-04-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/dv2svjk286iprbj8h0jkj7qs4na896g5/1560513600000/13206039755439676933/*/1Gzi-3nYGdU4hrQrQ-uifS6JLOF7eKGn-?e=download',`  At the zoom level you open at it is quite difficult to see against the background. Zoom in two levels and you should see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94918/discussion-between-gobinath-and-mike).